# JavaScript RegEx - First 2 characters letter, rest numbers OR just numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm completely new to RegEx and I've read a few things and it's just blown my mind.

So far this is what I have

```
/^([a-z]{2})?([0-9])/i
```

What I basically have is a text box that needs to accept a string where the first 2 characters are letters and the rest are numbers, or just numbers.

**Examples**.

**Match**:
`AB12345`
`12345`

**Not a match**:
`12345AB`
`AB12345AB`
`ACD1123`
`A332`

Any help and information would be great so I can see how it works and hopefully understand it myself!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the start `^` and end `$` of the string as well for checking, beside a quantifier for digits, *one or more* `+`.

```
/^([a-z]{2})?\d+$/i
```

```js
console.log(
    ['AB12345', '12345', '12345AB', 'AB12345AB', 'ACD1123', 'A332']
        .map(s => /^([a-z]{2})?\d+$/i.test(s))
);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You miss end anchor(`$`) and digit repetition(`\d+`):

```js
const reg = /^([a-z]{2})?([0-9]+)$/i

console.log(['AB12345', '12345'].map(v => reg.test(v)))

console.log(['12345AB', 'AB12345AB', 'ACD1123', 'A332'].map(v => reg.test(v)))
```